# How do I call a method in application helper from a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I defined a custom method in application_helper.rb file like the following:

```
def rxtrnk(line)
    rxTRNK = /\w{9,12}/m
    trnks = Array.new
    i = 0
    while i <= line.size
        if line[i].match(rxTRNK)
            trnks[i] = line[i].scan(rxTRNK)
        end
        i += 1
    end

    return trnks
  end
```

Then I tried to call it from a view like so:

```
<% @yo = rxtrnk(@rts)%>
```

But I get an error page like this:

```
NoMethodError in TrunksController#routesperswitch

undefined method `rxtrnk' for #<TrunksController:0x7f2dcf88>
```

I know this is a very newbie question, but I couldn't find solution from googling :(
Thanks for your help

edit/ here is the full application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
     def rxtrnk(line)
    rxTRNK = /\w{9,12}/m
    trnks = Array.new
    i = 0
    while i <= line.size
        if line[i].match(rxTRNK)
            trnks[i] = line[i].scan(rxTRNK)
        end
        i += 1
    end

    return trnks
  end

end
```

Answer (score 45):

not sure what is the issue, but you can solve this by include the application_helper in the controller

```
class TrunksController 
    include ApplicationHelper
end
```

In the view call:

```
<%= @controller.rxtrnk %>
```

Comment: Since the error is `NoMethodError in TrunksController#routesperswitch`, the method is being called in the context of a controller. Helper methods are not normally accessible from controllers, so you have to explicitly include the module where they're defined, as ez. suggests here.

Comment: As @Pete pointed out, you're not inheriting from your `ApplicationController`  - so if you fix your controller's first line to be `class TrunksController  < ApplicationController`, it should inherit your application_helper from the `ApplicationController`

Answer (score 21):

You should make sure that the helper containing the method you want to call is included by the current controller (in your case you want to include the ApplicationHelper). This is controlled using [the "`helper`" method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#M000490) in top of controllers.

Many Rails developers just include all helpers by default to avoid having to think about this. To do this add "`helper :all`" to the top of your ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all
end
```

You can also choose to only include the ApplicationHelper:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper ApplicationHelper
end
```

Answer (score 7):

your TrunksController might not be extending from the ApplicationController. The application Controller includes the Application helper so if you extend your controller form it, you should have access to those methods.

The start of your controller should be something like:

```
class TrunksController < ApplicationController
```

Comment: sorry, being a noob, I didn't quite get your response. Are you saying I already have a controller named Trunks.

Comment: He's saying that `TrunksController` is not inheriting from `ApplicationController` and therefore does not have access to the `ApplicationHelper`, which is the correct answer here.